# flask behind gunicorn and apache returning http

Tags: apache, flask

I wanted to make my app (finally) accessible through a reserved proxy:

> Request --> Apache --> gunicorn --> flask

After reading tons of thread and spending hours on this my actual apache config is:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName app.%my domain name%.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        SSLProxyEngine On
        ProxyPass / http://flask-server:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://flask-server:8000/

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.%my domain name%.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.%my domain name%.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I am using flask fixproxy, as it should have fixed the issue. But it didn't:

```
[...]
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix

login = LoginManager()
login.login_view = 'auth.login'
login.login_message = _l('Please log in to access this page.')
mail = Mail()
bootstrap = Bootstrap()

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)
    [...]
```

I added to all url_for `_external=True, _scheme='https'` which is working fine, but the app is still forwarding me to http at some places where I cannot add this properties (for example when I am not logged in).

I made two checks:
1)

```
curl -Ik  https://app.%my domain name%.com
HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Date: Thu, 19 Apr 2018 22:07:31 GMT
Server: gunicorn/19.7.1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 247
Location: http://app.%my domain name%.com/auth/login?next=%2F
Set-Cookie: session=...
HttpOnly; Path=/
```

2)

```
curl -Ik -H "X-Forwarded-Proto: https" https://app.%my domain name%.com
HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Date: Thu, 19 Apr 2018 22:07:22 GMT
Server: gunicorn/19.7.1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 247
Location: https://app.%my domain name%.com/auth/login?next=%2F
Set-Cookie: session=...
HttpOnly; Path=/
```

Seems like its more a apache problem. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the curl output I figured out what the problem is:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```

inside the apache config will solve it.
Don't forget to enable it (like I did):

```
a2enmod headers
```